# How to compare the value of two Double objects using the compare() method?

Tags: java, numbers, compareto

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the compare() method of Number class. I have declared two Double objects and tried to compare their values, however, the compiler prints out an error instead.

Why this is happening?

```
 Double i = new Double(3.4632);
 System.out.println(i.compareTo(m));
 Double m = new Double(96.235);

java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: <any>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your code is actually as written (with the `println` before the declaration of `m`) then the problem is most likely that you're using `m` before it's declared.  Move the `println` call to after the declaration:

```
    Double i = new Double(3.4632);
    Double m = new Double(96.235);
    System.out.println(i.compareTo(m));
```

Comment: This may seem odd to you if you come from the JavaScript world…